# react onselect passing value in addition to the Select option values

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass a value into an onselect. If I don't pass a parameter, I can access the values of the option selected just fine, like this:

```
onSelect={this.onItemSelect()}

onItemSelect = (option) => {
  console.log(option);
}
```

At that point, `option` will have a key and a display value. But I want to also pass in a parameter when calling onItemSelect. When I do that, my option values disappear. Here's what I've tried:

```
onSelect={this.onItemSelect(myId)}

onItemSelect = (myId, option) => {
  console.log(myId);
  console.log(option);
}
```

At that point, myId is fine, but option is undefined. How do I pass both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
onSelect={(option) => this.onItemSelect(myId, option)}
```